# SQL Find value in different tables from generic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

**Cats**:

```
| Id | Name  |
|----|-------|
|   1|   Cat1|
|   2|   Cat2|
|   3|   Cat3|
```

**Dogs**:

```
| Id | Name  |
|----|-------|
|  1 |   Dog1|
|  2 |   Dog2|
|  3 |   Dog3|
```

**Owner**:

```
| Id | Name  |TableName |EntityId|
|----|-------|--------------------
|  1 |   John|   Dog    |       1|
|  2 |   Pete|   Cat    |       1|
|  3 |Jessica|   Cat    |       2|
```

I have no control over the animal tables, I mean, may be N animal tables, cats and dogs was just an example.

There is a way to get the names of cats and dogs in one select query?
The result must be

```
| OwnerId | Name  |TableName |EntityId|AnimalName|
|---------|-------|-------------------------------
|  1      |   John|   Dog    |       1|     Dog1 |
|  2      |   Pete|   Cat    |       1|     Cat1 |
|  3      |Jessica|   Cat    |       2|     Cat2 |
```

Comment: Please include your sample desired output.

Comment: Why not `Pet` and `PetType` tables?

Comment: Thanks for answer , thats just sample data, what i have is a table called item_assignment with columns entity_type and entity_id, its a generic table that let me set an item for any entity, what I need is to list all the items and show the name of the entity that have the assignment of this item, I can't use Case because I have no control over the different entities that can have an item setted, so must be something generic. Sorry if I didn t make myself clear

Comment: You'd have to write a query that first finds all possible values in the `TableName` column and then *constructs* the `CASE` expression and `JOIN`s, and then run the query. Basically, someone's not using the database as relational databases are meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement for this:

```
select o.id, o.name, 
    case when o.tablename = 'dogs' then d.name else c.name end name
from owner o 
    left join cats c on o.entityid = c.id and o.tablename = 'cats'
    left join dogs d on o.entityid = d.id and o.tablename = 'dogs'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15f205/1)

---

As others have mentioned, if you have the opportunity to update your data model, then this could be a lot easier.  Have a `Pet` table, an `Owner` table and an `OwnerPet` table (x-ref table).  Then it's a simple query with `inner join`.

Comment: I can't use Case because I have no control over the different tables that can have an animal setted, that was just sample data, but may be n table animals

Comment: If you don't know the tables, then how are you going to join to them?  I imagine your only option is `dynamic sql`...

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would modify your table schema to something like:

- PetType

  - PetTypeId
  - PetTypeName
- Pet

  - PetId
  - PetTypeId
  - PetName
- Owner

  - OwnerId
  - OwnerName
- OwnerPet

  - OwnerId
  - PetId

Then you could do something like this:

```
select *
from Owner
join OwnerPet on OwnerPet.OwnerId = Owner.OwnerId
join Pet on OwnerPet.PetId = Pet.PetId
join PetType on Pet.PetTypeId = PetType.PetTypeId
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/535b7/2)

Comment: Thank you for answer Jhonny, thats just sample data, in fact, what i have is a table called item_assignment with columns entity_type and entity_id, its a generic table that let me set an item for any entity, so, I got a particular case where I need to list all the items and show the name of the entity that is set, I can't use Case because I have no control over the different entities that can have an item setted

Comment: and my solution doesn't require you to use case :)

Comment: Sorry, the part of the case was for the other answer

Comment: You should put that comment on that answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either left join or union to accomplish this task, both methods are mentioned below

```
SELECT 
    OW.ID,OW.Name,OW.TableName,OW.EntityId,
    CASE WHEN OW.TableName='Cat' THEN CA.Name ELSE DO.Name END AnimalName
FROM Owner OW
LEFT JOIN Cats CA ON OW.EntityId=CA.ID AND OW.TableName='Cat'
LEFT JOIN Dogs DO ON OW.EntityId=DO.ID AND OW.TableName='Dog'

SELECT 
    OW.ID,OW.Name,OW.TableName,OW.EntityId,CA.Name AnimalName
FROM Owner OW
JOIN Cats CA ON OW.EntityId=CA.ID AND OW.TableName='Cat'
UNION
SELECT 
    OW.ID,OW.Name,OW.TableName,OW.EntityId,DO.Name AnimalName
FROM Owner OW
JOIN Dogs DO ON OW.EntityId=DO.ID AND OW.TableName='Dog'
```

Comment: Can't do that because I have no control over the animals tables, may be N animal tables and with your pattern I will need one join or union for table, if I knew it.